# Why I can't store my object into my useState using Redux Toolkit

Tags: reactjs, redux

Why I can't store my data into my useState? By the way my data is a object.

const tasks = useSelector(taskSelector);

```
const [expanded, setExpanded] = useState();
  const [assignTask, setAssignTask] = useState();

  useEffect(() => {
    let currentUser = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('userData'));
    const data = tasks.filter(
      (assign) => assign.assigned === currentUser.fullname
    );
    setAssignTask(data);
    console.log(assignTask);

  }, []);
```

**Output**
console.log(data)
[image]

console.log(assignTask) => []

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the React docs:

> The setState function is used to update the state. It accepts a new state value and enqueues a re-render of the component.

> During subsequent re-renders, the first value returned by useState will always be the most recent state after applying updates.

I think that `data` gets set to `assignTask` on the next render. So if you're logging in from inside the `useEffect` straight away, it won't show the value yet.

Try logging `assignTask` outside of `useEffect`. It'll log over and over for each time the component renders and on one or more of them it should log your `data` value.